# Selenium chromedriver error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've got a linux server which runs the rails code, and a windows which runs selenium server. I have recently reinstalled windows, and selenium stopped working.

This is the error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Selenium::WebDriver:: Error::UnknownError The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, h ttps://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
```

- I've updated to the latest gem

  ```
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.48', '>= 2.48.1'
  ```
- The latest selenium server, [version 3.4.0](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
- the latest [ChromeDriver 2.29](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), which supports chrome v58.

I've read the [documentation about the error](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#troubleshooting), and I've done both solutions

- java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="G:...path...\chromedriver.exe" -jar
  selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
- I have chromedriver added to PATH (I can use it from anywhere in the
  console) which says upon execution that only local connections are allowed.

I have not modified my rails code, but just in case:

```
  Capybara.configure do |config| 
    Capybara.server_host='192....1.23'
    Capybara.server_port = '4000'
  end    
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome 
    caps.platform = :WINDOWS 
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
    Capybara.register_driver  :selenium do |app|
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
        :browser => :remote,
        :url => URI.parse("http://192....:4444/wd/hub"),
        :desired_capabilities => caps)
    end
  end
```

I've also tested window's port 4444 using Nmap from the linux pc.

Comment: I solved it by upgrading chromedriver by running `chromedriver-update 2.33` in the console.